# How can I check if a value already exists in a list before submitting a form? (SP 2010)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, jquery

I have a weekly update form that gets updated at the end of every week, but due to people making more than 1 a week I need to ensure that they can only make one a week. So I want to use the week number as a unique identifier to stop this problem.
I'm just not sure how to do this when it comes to Sharepoint lists.

```
function DashboardReportDropdown(projectRefNumber) {
//  var now = new Date(2014,07,11);
    var now = new Date();
    var filter = [];
    filter.push("(CalendarWeekNumber eq " + now.getWeek() + ")");
    filter.push("(ReportDate ge datetime'" + now.getFullYear() + "-01-01')");
    filter.push("(ReportDate le datetime'" + now.getFullYear() + "-12-31')");
    var params = $.param({
        '$select': 'Id,ReportDate',
        '$filter': filter.join(' and ')
    });
    var $dashboardReport = $('select[title="DashboardReport"]');
    $dashboardReport.change(function() {
        var dashboardReportId = $dashboardReport.val();
        if ($dashboardReport.val()) {
            $.getJSON('../______/listdata.svc/DashboardReportList(' + dashboardReportId + ')', function(data) {
                setWeeklyReportEndDate(data.d)
            });
        }

    })

    f($('ReportDate').length == 0) {
}
```

I put       f($('ReportDate').length == 0) {
 at the end as you can see, but I'm not sure how to link this to a list

Comment: Can you enforce unique values in the column settings?

Comment: If I did that would there be a way to get script saying "This weeks form has already been entered"?

Comment: Hey Wheeler, so given the type of entry there isn't an option for forcing unique values. I already have it outputting from a formula so could I add something to that? I'll post what it currently looks like above

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) to search the list for records matching a query. The `GetListItems` operation is documented [here](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems&referringTitle=Lists). You said your field doesn't allow enforcing unique values, so I don't know what data type it is. You would change the Type='DateTime' to match your field. Types listed [here](http://blog.halan.se/post/Undocumented-CAML-Field-Element-types.aspx). This function searches a list named "test" for an item where the field Date = 10/1/2015

```
function checkReportDate(_stringDate){  
    var itemCount;

    //reformat date to YYYY-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ
    formattedDate = "2015-10-01T00:00:00Z";

    var myCAML = "";
    myCAML += "<Query>";
    myCAML += "<Where>";
    myCAML +=     "<Eq>";
    myCAML +=         "<FieldRef Name='Date' />";
    myCAML +=         "<Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>" + formattedDate + "</Value>";
    myCAML +=     "</Eq>";
    myCAML += "</Where>";
    myCAML += "</Query>";

    var spPromise1 = $().SPServices({
        webURL: SITE,
        operation: "GetListItems",
        listName: "test",
        async: false,
        CAMLQuery: myCAML
        }
    });
    spPromise1.done(function(){
        itemCount = $(spPromise1.responseXML).SPFilterNode("rs:data").attr("ItemCount");
    });

    return itemCount;
}
```